# InstaSharp: Can not get the access token

Tags: c#, wpf, instagram-api, instasharp

I am using InstaSharp in a WPF application. I have read the documentation of InstaSharp. And here is the code I tried.

```
InstagramConfig config = new InstagramConfig(clientId, clientSecret, redirectUri, realtimeUri);

var oAuth = new OAuth(config);

var scopes = new List<OAuth.Scope>();

var link = InstaSharp.OAuth.AuthLink(config.OAuthUri + "authorize", config.ClientId, config.RedirectUri, scopes, InstaSharp.OAuth.ResponseType.Code);
var authInfo = await oAuth.RequestToken(clientId);
```

Now the problem is that I am getting **authInfo** as null. Which means I am getting the accesstoken as null. When I copy paste the **link**(generated by above code) in the browser, it asks me for authorization and generates an access token but I can not get it programmatically with the above code.

Can someone please help me get the access token ?

Comment: When do you check the `authInfo`? Do you wait till `RequestToken` return? Do you notice the `await` at the beginning?

Comment: Any solution to this problem? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: Hi,, what to use for redirectUri?